# How to use existing soap web service into spring application?

Tags: java, soap

I am new to Soap web-service ,I have existing soap web-service URL like below

**http://mywebservice/firstwsdl.asmx?wsdl**

I want to use this web-service into my project .How Can I do this ,Any one help me .In my project I am using Maven also .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps can give you idea where to start for your first soap service -

**1. Add Dependencies to your pom**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**2. Generate stubs using maven plugin**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>com.test.package.stub</generatePackage>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://mywebservice/firstwsdl.asmx?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

**3. Add to your spring application context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>

    <!-- Define the SOAP version used by the WSDL -->
    <bean id="soapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- The location of the generated Java files -->
    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.test.package.stub"/>

    <!-- Configure Spring Web Services -->
    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="soapMessageFactory"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
        <property name="defaultUri" value="http://mywebservice/hello"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**4. finally your service class**

Request and response classes will be available under the package you specified in the marshaller bean package with jaxb annotations - com.test.package.stub :

```
 @Service
    public class TestService {
        @Autowired
        private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

        public Double getValue(String paramOne) {

             request.setParam(paramOne);

            Response response = (Response) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(
                    request);

            return response.Result();
        }
    }
```